# Scikit-learn kmeans clustering

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

I'm supposed to be doing a kmeans clustering implementation with some data. The example I looked at from http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html shows their test data in 2 columns... however, the data I'm given is 68 subjects with 78 features (so 68x78 matrix). How am I supposed to create an appropriate input for this?

I've basically just tried inputting the matrix anyway, but it doesn't seem to do what I want... and I don't know why it would. I'm pretty confused as to what to do.

```
        data = np.rot90(data)
        centroids,_ = kmeans(data,2)
        # assign each sample to a cluster
        idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

        # some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
        plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
             data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or')
        plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
        show()
```

I honestly don't know what kind of code to show you.. the data format I told you was already described. Otherwise, it's the same as the tutorial I linked.

Comment: Show the code that you've actually tried.  What specific error messages or unexpected behaviour are you seeing, other than "doesn't seem to do what I want"?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ILmPQS3.png I don't understand why some that are closer to one cluster are labeled as another... and honestly I was kinda hoping that they'd be more separated (but I suppose it's possible they aren't).

Comment: Looks like you're using scipy not scikit-learn.  Should probably change the tag.   I'm fairly new to kmeans myself.  With that said, 78 features seems like a lot.  Are all 78 numeric, non categorical variables?

Comment: Yeah, they are. That being said, is my data even organized correctly? The example makes it seem like x,y coordinates.. I have no idea how my data could even be graphed. I simply have 68 vectors of length 78. I feel like I'm really missing out on something and becoming frustrated.

Comment: You're only plotting 2 of 78 dimensions.  The blue points that look closer to the red centroid in this 2-dimensional **projection** are actually closer to the blue centroid in the full 78-dimensional space.

Comment: Amit, I feel bad for asking this.. but what is the correction to this, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your visualization only uses the **first two dimensions**.

That is why these points appear to be "incorrect" - they are closer in a different dimension.

Have a look at the next two dimensions:

```
plot(data[idx==0,2],data[idx==0,3],'ob',
         data[idx==1,2],data[idx==1,3],'or')
    plot(centroids[:,2],centroids[:,3],'sg',markersize=8)
    show()
```

... repeat for all remaining of oyur 78 dimensions...

At this many features, (squared) Euclidean distance gets meaningless, and k-means results tend to become as good as random convex partitions.

To get a more representative view, consider using [MDS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html) to project the data into 2d for visualization. It should work reasonably fast with just 68 subjects.

**Please include visualizations in your questions.** We don't have your data.